# Is there any difference in performance between these two for loop?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

As I said: Is there any difference (in performance) between these two `for` loop?
Between this:

```
    var n:int = displayObjects_.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        var currentObject:DisplayObject = displayObjects_[i];
        currentObject.width = newWidth;
    }
```

and this:

```
    var n:int = displayObjects_.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        displayObjects_[i].width = newWidth;
    }
```

I tested them before. The result said the first one was faster but I don't know if I did it right.

Comment: How did you time the two loops? What was the difference in duration? How many times did you run the timer? Have you tried running it for, say 1000 cycles and checked if there is any significant margin between the two?

Comment: I don't remember the margin between them but I use AsUnit to test them for some cycles perhaps 1000.

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there were any significant differences between the two. Besides, such optimizations make very little impact in a language like ActionScript. Additionally, they're open to vagaries of the virtual machine such as available system resources. I'd just take the second one for being more readable and save my optimization efforts on choosing better data structures or algorithms.

Comment: Tested them again. They were alternating faster than the other when number of cycles changed.

Comment: Tested with 100 0000 cycles, the way number 1 was constantly faster than number 2 and 3vilguy's way at least 100 miliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not really an answer to your question, but if you're looking for fastest way to iterate through this array you should do:

```
for each(var currentObject:DisplayObject in displayObjects_) {
    currentObject.width = newWidth;
}
```

Comment: Trust me, it is : >
Also, if you're using Array you can use Vector.<DisplayObject> instead and it's gonna be even faster.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this out on a bare-bones project using SDK 4.6. This is the code.

```
public class Main extends Sprite 
{

    public function Main() 
    {
        var displayObjects_:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
        {
            displayObjects_.push(new Sprite());
        }

        var start:int = getTimer();
        for (i = 0; i < displayObjects_.length; i++)
        {
            var currentObject:Sprite = displayObjects_[i];
            currentObject.width = 100;
        }
        var end:int = getTimer()
        trace(end, start, end - start);

        start = getTimer();
        for (i = 0; i < displayObjects_.length; i++)
        {
            displayObjects_[i].width = 100;
        }
        end = getTimer()
        trace(end, start, end - start);
    }
}
```

These are the results.

> Done(0)
>   [Starting debug session with FDB]
>   16703 16250 453
>   17141 16703 438

Like I said, it would be very surprising to see any difference between the two. You'll probably see more improvements through using Vector instead of Array. Otherwise, this stuff is too mundane to fuss over.

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Actionscript compiler automatically moves variable definitions to the begin of the function. So, this loop doesn't declare variable each time, first sample the same that:

```
  var currentObject:DisplayObject;
  var n:int = displayObjects_.length;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        currentObject = displayObjects_[i];
        currentObject.width = newWidth;
    }
```

So, I think the difference only in one additional variable declare and it willn't affects performance. But 3vilguy's example is better.